# Why after 100 clients connection to postgres the speed of request processing begins to degrade?

Tags: postgresql

I read an article that said that after 100 connection proccesing speed start to degrade. Hoewever there wasn't any link to source to prove it. But there was said that this is due to the particular implementation of Postgres itself. And I'm really curious to know why, but unfortunately my search didn't succeed, that why I'm asking here.

Comment: General rule: https://dzone.com/articles/close-your-database-connections -every opened connection has to have allocated resources on the RDBMS server

Comment: The resources of a server are limited. 100 connections has been identified as a good default value for the number of open connections. Of course if you have a server that has more resources (CPUs, memory, hard disks) your server can cope with more connections. If you have a low-end server, even 20 might be too much

Answer (score 1):

There is some truth lurking behind that statement, but it is false in the simple form in which it is stated here.

Establishing the thousandth connection to a PostgreSQL database won't be significantly slower than establishing the first one.

As long as the connections are idle, they do only little harm:

- Each one will consume a couple of MB memory to hold data like the catalog cache.
- Some operations, like creating a snapshot at the begin of a query, will take longer, since they have to consider each database connection.

The big problem is that you have no way to control these connections, and they could suddenly become active processing queries. This will kill you for two reasons:

- Either the CPU or the I/O subsystem (or both) will become totally overloaded, and processing will come to a crawl *for everyone*, as the operating system is busy with context switches or I/O waits.
- Each connection can use `work_mem` memory multiple times to process sorts, hashes and the like, so unless you want to go out of memory, you have to be very stingy configuring `work_mem`, which will hurt query performance even if there is no load on the system.

For these reasons it is advisable to keep `max_connections` low and use a connection pool as a bottleneck.

Answer (score -2):

> But there was said that this is due to the particular implementation of Postgres itself.

in comparition with MS SQL:
MS SQL have assigned/allocated memory for Instance, PostgreSQL have assigned/alloacated memory for each connection.
If you have active 100 connection you should have allocated separate memory buffor for each separate connection.

for example in one of my customer office I have a solution where 10 Workstation is connecting to about 14 databases,
This all workstation could at the same time crate about 100 different connection, If we want to allocate about 100MB/Connection this mean that we need about 10GB RAM only for PostgreSQL connection. 
But you must to know that even if each workstation is searching the same data, then you still need separate allocated RAM for each connection, this mean that much more frequently SQL engine need to read data from DISC instead from RAM.